# Attempt to Update FMDB via swipe gesture of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

Is there a way to update an FMDB via swipe gesture of a UITableViewCell? I would like to be able to use the existing delete button to change a single column in the table but everything I try seems to result in the application crashing.  I would also like to be able to create an insert button to do something similar but cannot find the code to do this without creating a subview.  I posted an example of one of the things I have tried.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); // Get the documents directory

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"passages.db"]];

    self.database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
    [self.database open];

    [self.database executeUpdate:@"UPDATE passages set favorite=?", @NO, nil];
    [self.database close];

}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Comment: when you say slide button, do you mean the `UISlider` control? If so, then post the code for the selector you call when the slider value changes. And do you really want to update the DB for every value change? Or the last value that was selected on the slider?

Comment: I'm trying to add a function like in the mail app when you swipe sideways, you can delete mail from there.  I am trying to change it so that it only changes the value of one column (ie when you press delete on that view, it changes the favorites bool to nil)

Comment: What is the type of the column `favorite` in the table `passages`? As far as I know sqlite does not support BOOL so this is either a varchar or ideally should be an integer. Your query is wrong regardless of that though. What is @NO? It should  either be @"NO" or NO. And the `?` in `UPDATE passages set favorite=?` doesn't look right either.

Comment: I was using FMDB and the @NO is converted properly into an integer in the table.  The query works elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Doing this should give you the swipe to delete functionality out of the box
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       //your code for updating favorite
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I got it! Thank you, I didn't take out something I should have and then just needed to reload the data at the end!